# Obtain count of fields from grouped rows

Tags: mongodb, group-by, count, aggregation-framework, aggregation

Data:

```
[
  { created_at: "2020-05-08T18:46:08.020Z", view: true, cta: false },
  { created_at: "2020-05-08T19:00:00.020Z", view: true, cta: true },
  { created_at: "2020-05-08T19:30:45.020Z", view: true, cta: false },
  { created_at: "2020-05-08T19:55:50.020Z", view: true, cta: true }
]
```

When I group the data on hourly interval via created_at I get the count of unique created_at just fine.

```
  $group: {
    $hour: { hour: '$created_at' },
    count: { $sum: 1 }

  }
```

Result:

```
   hour: 18, count: 1,
   hour: 19, count: 3
```

Now, how do I also include the count of `cta` and `view` field, when the field value is true. I would like to obtain result like:

```
    [{ hour: 18, ctaCount: 0, viewCount: 1 }],
    [{ hour: 19, ctaCount: 2, viewCount: 3 }]
```

Tried grouping with multiple group operators and it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and refer to `cta` field directly since it's bool:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { hour: { $hour: "$created_at" } },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
            ctaCount: { $sum: { $cond: [ "$cta", 1, 0 ] } }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CtxZpaNYWu7)

Comment: One more doubt. How would you do the same if cta field was in a different collection all together? @mick

Also what if CTA field was a string?

Comment: No, you need to $lookup first in such case and then when you have all the data in the same collection you can specify a boolean expression in `$cond`